# Android - SMS Loopback

Tags: android, android-emulator, sms

I wish to achieve a SMS loopback, i.e. to send and receive SMS from the same application. In order to do so, I have created a class that extends `BroadcastReciever`, implemented the `onReceive()` method, and declared the relevant permissions.

I verified the implementation by sending a SMS using telnet.
I want to automate the telnet process, i.e. having the application test itself by sending the SMS. In order to do so, I invoke the following method in the main activity, but the `BroadcastReceiver` is never called:

```
private final void sendSMS() {
    final TelephonyManager telMgr = (TelephonyManager)
            getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    final int len = telMgr.getLine1Number().length(); 
    final String phoneNum = telMgr.getLine1Number().substring(len - 4, len);
    final String msg = "msg"; 
    SmsManager.getDefault().sendTextMessage(phoneNum, null, msg, null, null);
}
```

Any clue what is wrong...?

**UPDATE:** Note that the code above is intended for the emulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I understand you question right, but are you trying send an SMS from the emulator to itself? As far as I know, that is not possible. Just load up another emulator, and send messages between them.

Since telnet commands work, your BroadcastReceiver is probably correctly implemented, but you should probably attach the code for it anyways... Its hard to troubleshoot code you can't see :)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Why do you claim that it is impossible to have the emulator send a SMS back to itself?

Comment: I claim that because it has never worked on any of my emulators. Not through the built in SMS application, nor through SmsManager. When using the built in SMS application, the SMS will be marked as sent, but you will never receive it :(

Comment: That is exactly the problem :(